# Alternative for TreeView widget in Universal Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, treeview

I have to develop UWP program, and I have found that to use a regular TreeView Widget, what is supported in Windows Forms, is too much overhead. So I have to substitute this part of my GUI with something else. 
This is an example of my desired data hierarchy

- House #1

  - Person #1
  - Person #2
  - Person #3
  - Person #4
- House #2

  - Person #1
  - Person #2
  - Person #3
- House #3

  - Person #1

TreeView Widget is good because I can select all subnodes of a parent node (all "persons" in a "house"), the alternative has to support it as well and as to make this alternative solution as user-friendly as possible

Comment: Define "too much overhead".  What actual problems are you having?  How large is your data set?  I've never used UWP, but I've used WPF, and with UI and (if necessary) data virtualization, I'd think you could make the `TreeView` perform adequately.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, here it is written that to use TreeView, you have to add another C++ project to yr UWP project, and it is a bit tricky for me, because then I would not be able to change my .xaml file in designer.

Comment: What did you mean about 'change my .xaml file in designer.'? What's your final requirement? Did you want a TreeView control in UWP?